# How to strip square brackets from string in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a variable with value enclosed in square brackets.
eg: my $status=[Calculate version=SUCCESS, cleanup stale processes=SUCCESS, Update version=SUCCESS, mail=null, Post Actions=SUCCESS]

Now, I want to strip square brackets from above string. I am trying below regex, but it's not working for square brackets.

```
$status =~ s/[{}]//g;  #This is working for curly braces
$status =~ s/[\[\]]//g; #is not working
```

Can you help.

```
#!perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
my $status="[Calculate version=SUCCESS, cleanup stale processes=SUCCESS, Update version=SUCCESS, mail=null, Post Actions=SUCCESS]";
$status =~ s/[\[\]]//g;
print "status is : $status\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass#Bracketed-Character-Classes):

> A `[` is not special inside a character class, unless it's the start of a POSIX character class (see "POSIX Character Classes" below). It normally does not need escaping.

> A `]` is normally either the end of a POSIX character class (see "POSIX Character Classes" below), or it signals the end of the bracketed character class. If you want to include a `]` in the set of characters, you must generally escape it.

> However, if the `]` is the first (or the second if the first character is a caret) character of a bracketed character class, it does not denote the end of the class (as you cannot have an empty class) and is considered part of the set of characters that can be matched without escaping.

So...

```perl
$status =~ s/[][]//g;
```

---

However,

```perl
$status =~ s/[\[\]]//g;
```

works for me. Not sure why it's not for you, unless there's something else going on in your real code you're not showing.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. I tried both of the above already. Seems like it's breaking at space.
status is : Calculate

Comment: Updated the snippet in my question, and it works. It's my fault. Seems like I have bug in my script. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`tr`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Quote-Like-Operators):

```
my $status = "[Calculate version=SUCCESS, cleanup stale processes=SUCCESS, Update version=SUCCESS, mail=null, Post Actions=SUCCESS]";
$status =~ tr/[]//d;
print "$status\n";
# Calculate version=SUCCESS, cleanup stale processes=SUCCESS, Update version=SUCCESS, mail=null, Post Actions=SUCCESS
```